# How to map JSON data with @RequestBody annotation

Tags: json, spring

I send a HTTP request to Spring Framework backend from the client with a JSON object that contains a property that is an id to another object.

The @RequestBody does not know how to handle this reference and gives me
400 invalid request.

I've read that I can create a custom Mapper for my class. Is this the only
solution or I require some annotation?

If the custom mapper is the single solution, could you give an example?

My code example:

```
public class Book {

@Id
private String id;

@DBRef
private Author author;

private String name;

//getters and setters
}
```

The Controller:

```
...
@RequestMapping("/book")
private Book book(@RequestBody Book book) {
//code
}
...
```

The JSON sent by client:

```
{'name': 'something', 'author': '55422e51dcca4511fd8a0ffc'}
```

Where author is it's id.

Comment: Spring can do Json to Object marshalling out of the box, but you have to make sure to configure your application context correctly. You need to register a Json converter, e.g. the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter. If you use annotations to configure your application, simply add EnableWebMvc to your Configuration class and RestController to your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do either of below.

1. Change your method to below.Use `ModelAttribute` instead.

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/book")

   private Book book(@ModelAttribute Book book) {

   }
   ```
2. If you still want to use RequestBody,then do like below.

@RequestMapping("/book")

```
private Book book(@RequestBody String body) {

  //Now use any JSON parser(Gson or Jackson) 

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Book book = gson.fromJson(body, Book.class);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use spring and add api **gson** dependency, this last is necessary for send a json object DTO into **@RequestBody**. any examples use api jackson but gson is used in last versions of spring